# Device orientation in mobile Opera is not working

Tags: javascript, opera, android-sensors

I have issues making deviceorientation working in Opera browser.

This code works well on my Android/Chrome:

```
  window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(e) {
    console.log(e.webkitCompassHeading || e.compassHeading || e.alpha || 0);
  });
```

However Opera says `0` all the time. I also tried `AbsoluteOrientationSensor` and check it with Permission API:

```
alert("AbsoluteOrientationSensor" in window); // Opera says true

Promise.all([navigator.permissions.query({ name: "accelerometer" }),
             navigator.permissions.query({ name: "magnetometer" }),
             navigator.permissions.query({ name: "gyroscope" })])
   .then(results => {
      if (results.every(result => result.state === "granted")) {
        alert("Permissions granted");
      } else {
        alert("Permissions blocked");
      }
    });

// Opera says Permissions granted
```

but again: sensor reading (from the basic example in the link below) works in Chrome and is silent in Opera. MDN says [Deviceorientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation) and [AbsoluteOrientationSensor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbsoluteOrientationSensor) should work in Opera, so what am I missing?